# Using separate databases for development and production with flutter and firebase on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I want to use separate google-services plist files (a Dev and a Prod database in this case) with flutter and iOS.

With android it just involved copying the relevant google services json file at build time automatically. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do the same/similar on iOS using flutter.

Every example I can find looks more targeted at an iOS app rather than a flutter app.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to do the same with flutter ?

Comment: I am looking to do same thing, will check back here when we figure out how we will do it. Here is where I am starting: https://medium.com/@salvatoregiordanoo/flavoring-flutter-392aaa875f36